# wired connection detected but no internet access in ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet

i am having ubuntu 14.04 lts on machine.Though it is showing connected to LAN in network manager but it cant access internet.

Answer (score 8):

There are few steps you should follow while debugging internet connectivity
I assume you use DHCP and NetworkManager for configuration.

1) Check if you have IP address assigned
Open terminal end enter

```
ifconfig
```

If you see something like this containing inet addr than it is ok

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:74:3d:92:90 
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
```

2) Check if you have default gateway assigned. Open terminal and enter

```
netstat -r
```

If you see similar output containg line beginning with default than it is ok

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

3) Check if you can ping default gateway. Open terminal and enter

```
 ping 192.168.1.1
```

where 192.168.1.1 should be replaced with adress you see in nestat -r output

You should see something like this

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.265 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.235 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.221 ms
```

4) Check if you have DNS server assigned. Open terminal and enter

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

You should see at least one line containing word nameserver

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

5) Check if you can ping DNS server. Open terminal and enter

```
 ping 8.8.8.8
```

where 8.8.8.8 should be replaced with address you see in cat /etc/resolv.conf output

You should see something like this

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=48 time=25.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=48 time=26.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=48 time=24.9 ms
```

6) Check if you can resolve DNS names. Open terminal and enter

```
host www.google.pl
```

You should see something like this

```
www.google.pl has address 216.58.209.67
```

If any of the steps fails than it needs further investigation.

Comment: All this worked for me but still no internet connection. DNS is working fine but i cant ping the ip address on this computer.

Answer (score 0):

Switch firewall off temporarily. See if that works.

Darek's helpful checklist identified the source of the problem.

Was unable to (3) ping my default gateway.

Because... firewall.

Answer (score 0):

if you got **step 6** of @Darek's answer and saw this in your
**/etc/resolv.conf** file has comments like this: (it might be empty without the commments too)

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

generate the DNS contents like this:

**Step 1:**
Install the **resolvconf** package, it enables you to make permanent changes to the resolv.conf file
`sudo apt install resolvconf`

**Step 2:** 
 
Edit `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and add the following:

```
   # Make edits to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head.
   nameserver 8.8.4.4
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

**Step 3:** 
Restart the **resolvconf** service.

`sudo service resolvconf restart`

**NB:** This problem may arise if you upgraded from a previous version of ubuntu to 18.04